# Bad feeling in the heart

Tags: shirk, kufr

I have, in these last days, felt a bad feeling in my heart. Let me explain so you can insha a Lah, with the Quran and Sunnah, explain it to me.

So these last days, when I say the shahada, I feel like my heart is not safe, and that there is shirk being committed in my heart.

Is this a sign of kufr or shirk and what does it mean in the Quran or Sunnah.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Alaikum,
These are waswasa (whispers) from Shaytaan. Do not pay any attention to them and say “A’udhu billahi mina-shaytan-ir-rajeem (I seek refuge in Allah from Shaytaan the cursed one). Getting whispers from Shaytaan is normal for the believing Muslims because Shaytaan is not happy with our belief in Allah. So don’t pay attention to it. Prophet Muhammad (s) said that Allah has forgiven the ummah for whatever thought that may cross their mind as long as they do not speak or act upon them. Having thoughts like these are not a sign of kufr or shirk don’t worry and actually are a sign of strong faith in Allah (swt) as long as you reject them, seek refuge with Allah (swt), disapprove of them and don’t speak or act upon them

Also, Some of the Sahabas came to Prophet Muhammad (s) and said, ‘We find in ourselves thoughts that are too terrible to speak of.’ He said, ‘Are you really suffering from that?’ They said, ‘Yes.’ He said, ‘That is a clear sign of faith.’” (Sahih Muslim).

It was also narrated from Abu Hurayrah (r), that the Prophet (saw) said, “The Shaytan comes to one of you and says, ‘Who created such and such? Who created such and such?’ Until he says, ‘Who created your Lord?!’ If that happens to any of you, let him seek refuge with Allah and put a stop to these thoughts.”

It was narrated from Ibn ‘Abbas (r) that a man came to Prophet Muhammad (s) and said, “I think thoughts to myself, which I would rather be burnt to a cinder than speak of them.” Prophet Muhammad (s) said, “Praise be to Allah, Who has reduced all his [the Shaytan’s] plots to mere whispers.” (Abu Dawood)